# Как задать отступы у слайдов в Swiper-slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, слайдер, swiper, swipe

Без отступов всё хорошо, а с ними видно вместо двух слайдов три

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы кастомно выравнивали слайды прописав свой CSS, лучше потрите его и используйте выравнивание слайдов с помощью дефолтных параметров из мануала к слайдеру, там всё нужное есть.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство [spaceBetween](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-spaceBetween).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
new Swiper(".swiper", {
    spaceBetween: 15,
});
```